# How to compress a very big file containing only a little data

Tags: compression

I've bought a 250 GB SSD, run a full format on it, installed Win10 on it, cloned the entire disk using the *dd* command in a Linux terminal to have a backup in case my SSD breaks sometime, so now I have a disk image file with a size of approx. 250 GB that looks like this:

```
| --- some data (approx. 17 GB) --- | ------ no data at all, only nulls ------ |
```

I started to compress the file using *zip* and expected that *zip* would be intelligent enough to give me a *.zip* of approx. 17 GB of size, but after hours of zipping and my *.zip* reaching over 50 GB already, I interrupted the process and came here to ask you whether there's another potential ways to do this.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but for making disk images, consider using some disk imaging software, such as clonezilla or partimage (or one of many commercial products available). They will do compression on the fly, and the whole process will be much faster as well.

Comment: Note that for a Win10 partition, `dism` is the preferred (and Microsoft supported) method of capturing a disk image. It is file-based, not block-based as `dd` is, but unlike other file-based compression tools, it fully supports ACLs and all other NTFS data structures and is therefore suitable for backing up/restoring the operating system itself. It supports both compression and deduplication.

Comment: Acronis True Image ISO does a pretty god job of keeping partition size down with a full image and is a breeze to restore.  Also, you can restore over SMB so you can store your restore images in a centralized backup location and restore over the network.

Comment: I chose the dd+zip method because it worked for Linux (also restoring went without problems) and I was afraid if I use some other tool that doesn't necessarily produce a bit-for-bit copy, I can't be sure then whether the backup would be ok and easy to restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the empty part of the drive contains only nulls?  There's probably a lot of deleted garbage out there.  The stuff on the distribution package was no doubt stored compressed.  It was decompressed for installation and then the files were **copied** to their targets, then all the temporary junk was deleted when it was done.  Thus I would expect to find deleted data at least as great as the installation size - the space taken up by swap files.

Beyond that, when it comes to highly compressible data I have found that in really bad cases compressing the archive will shrink it further.  Most compressors have a maximum length of a dictionary item, when the redundancy in your file vastly exceeds this (as would be if your problem was what you thought it was) you end up with runs of the code for the dictionary entry that get compressed.  (And note that I have also seen a small benefit from compressing an archive that contained a vast number of small files--the files didn't compress any more but the housekeeping data did.)

That being said, what you need to do here is copy your partition, then shrink the copied partition as small as you can (nuke your swap and hibernate files if you can), then do what you did to the result.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume that any empty space on a disk contains only 0's or completely consistent data.  Deleting a file does not automatically write 0's to the area of disk it occupied, it just marks any pointers to that data as invalid and waits for something else to need to write data in that space. In the meantime whatever data was there is still technically there but it is more difficult to get at.

You also cannot assume that a new disk will be zeroed either, it may well be that the data is completely random garbage from the manufacturing and test procedures.

If you absolutely must have a disk image generated in this way then you need to fill that empty space with consistent data yourself first.

On Windows you can download a tool called [sdelete](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete) and it has an option to properly zero fill a disk: `sdelete -z`

This will be incredibly time consuming on larger disks and could take hours or even days depending on the size of your disk.

The smarter option is to use tools that understand the disk format and only store data that actually needs to be stored to begin with and ignores "blank" space on the disk.

- Macrium Reflect
- Clonezilla
- Acronis Trueimage

Those are a few, but there are a lot more disk imaging softwares out there.

Comment: I assumed that the empty space has only 0s (or at least almost) because I fully formatted the SSD and then immediately cloned it after the Win install was completed. (The installation files might take up some more place as Loren said, that's true, I didn't think of that.) I certainly give *sdelete* a try and if it works and makes the zip small enough, that will be the most preferred solution by me, because then I can stick to dd's bit-for-bit feature and also don't need to install any additional disk imaging software. But for this, I need some time...

Comment: `sdelete` took me 7 hours. Then, I cloned the whole SSD using `dd`, then I zipped the disk image file, and now the `.zip` has 21 GB. I don't say it's more practical than an imaging tool made specifically for this purpose, but somehow a clone made with dd I just trust more. Thanks for sdelete!

Comment: Fair enough. I can't really argue that it is worse, except that you don't really want to do this sort of thing on a regular basis as it could be prematurely wearing out the ssd and, as you have noticed, it can take a lot of time. If the end result is something that you are happier with (a complete disk image *is* potentially better than trusting that some random Linux tool is understanding the Windows disk format properly) then it is serving its purpose. Glad to have helped you find the right set of tools.